# Would a bat's wing be improved with feathers?

Tags: creature-design, flight

Bats and birds have very different wings, but if you were to combine them, giving bats feathers on top of their membranous wings, would that improve their flight? Or would it just be a useless, maybe debilitating addition?

Comment: I don't know but I think you should definitely watch this video, *BAT Flight vs BIRDS, with SLOWMO*, to get insight https://youtu.be/LxzyAadoyzY?t=150

Comment: Flight has limited margins for error. Just plunking new stuff on flight critical parts is likely to be bad. With some evolution cycles, it would generate a more optimized solution.  Would many generations later  be improved by some measure? Without research all answers would be speculation.

Answer (score 6):

They would be worse.

Bats are already better fliers than birds. they are more [maneuverable](https://journals.biologists.com/jeb/article/218/5/653/14631/Bat-flight-aerodynamics-kinematics-and-flight), more [efficient](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1748-3182/4/1/015001/meta), and [faster](https://www.newscientist.com/article/2112044-speedy-bat-flies-at-160kmh-smashing-bird-speed-record/) in the air.

The big advantage birds have is a much more efficient respiratory system and a decoupled flight mechanism which allows them to be decent at flight and good at running at the same time, whereas bats are excellent flyers and crap runners.

extra sources https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rspb.2012.0346

Comment: Birds also have the advantage of not as delicate wings.  A bat's thin skin membrane can be damaged easily while feathers are a bit more sturdy.

Comment: @Nathan not really bat wings are pretty sturdy compared to feathers. the other big advantage birds have is a decoupled flight mechanism, birds are far better runners than bats because the hind legs are not involved in flight.

Answer (score 2):

> Or would it just be a useless, maybe debilitating addition?

Yes, it would make their flight worse or impossible. Bats are finely tuned animals with millennia of evolution.

Both feathers and skin exist to create lift, the advantage to feathers is that they're light and slide over each other, (not because they're feathers a single feather is not useful) so the shape can be tweaked instantly. If they're overlaying skin then they cannot do this because they're constrained by the underlying skin.

Comment: That last line about constrained by the underlying skin doesn't make sense. Birds have underlying skin and that doesn't cause problems with feathers.

Comment: @DavidR no, they have skin where the quills are attached, not underlying the whole flight feathers

Comment: the lack of connection between feathers actually makes birds worse fliers not better. it allows the feathers to twist and deform under loading.

Comment: @Kilisi  Are you British and prone to understatement?  Bats have been evolving for tens of thousands of times as long as the "millennia" you menton.

Comment: @Golding Millennia is as much an expression as an individual word.

Answer (score 1):

Feathers *instead* of bat wing, yes.

A slight adjustment to the flapping motion and flying style would be required, but feathers do make a lighter, more aerodynamically efficient flying wing than skin does.
Of course, a flying rat with feathered wings would look *very* much like a small bird.

But feathers *in addition* to skin membrane wings? Nope, Nope, Nope.
Added nonfunctional mass, movement restriction (skin folds **much** better than feathers), and some disruption of the airflow over the wing, requiring a different stroke.

Comment: I'd say it depends on the kind of flight. Soaring? Feathered bird wings are definitely better. Active flight? Gotta give it to the bats, since their wings, being much more flexible, are also more capable of maximizing the effects of the downstroke and minimize resistance in the upstroke by "closing" the wing more, making them more energy efficient in active flight.

Comment: @ProjectApex yep. Effectively, bats do not "fly".. They "Swim" through the air. Using displacement of air, rather than true aerodynamics with laminar flow and Bernoulli and all that sophisticated stuff. And at bat size scaling, this works just *fine*. Makes for very good maneuverability, too. Works so well that bats can afford to retain their jawbone, even some teeth, instead of going for the less capable but lighter beak that birds simply *had* to go for.

Comment: bats are MORE efficient fliers than birds not less. https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rspb.2012.0346

Comment: @john um that's actually completely not what your linked article states. It says that bats are more efficient wing-flappers, but inferior fliers.

Comment: @PcMan where does it say they are inferior fliers? Also if you look at the links on my answer you also see that bats are more maneuverable and faster.